# Render view to string does not work on server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'am working on a method that converts a view to PDF. I finally got it working but when i published it to to the testing server it wouldnt work? it just gave me this error:

> InvalidOperationException: Cannot find compilation library location for package 'Microsoft.NETCore.App'

I have found out that it fails when i try to convert view to string..


This is the [article](https://ppolyzos.com/2016/09/09/asp-net-core-render-view-to-string/) where i found the service i use to convert my view to string

```
public interface IViewRenderService
{
    Task<string> RenderToStringAsync(string viewName, object model);
}

public class ViewRenderService : IViewRenderService
{
    private readonly IRazorViewEngine _razorViewEngine;
    private readonly ITempDataProvider _tempDataProvider;
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    public ViewRenderService(IRazorViewEngine razorViewEngine,
         ITempDataProvider tempDataProvider,
         IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
         _razorViewEngine = razorViewEngine;
         _tempDataProvider = tempDataProvider;
         _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public async Task<string> RenderToStringAsync(string viewName, object model)
    {
        var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext { RequestServices = _serviceProvider };
        var actionContext = new ActionContext(httpContext, new RouteData(), new ActionDescriptor());

        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            var viewResult = _razorViewEngine.GetView(viewName, viewName, false);

            if (viewResult.View == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException($"{viewName} does not match any available view");
            }

            var viewDictionary = new ViewDataDictionary(new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(), new ModelStateDictionary())
            {
                Model = model
            };

            var viewContext = new ViewContext(
                actionContext,
                viewResult.View,
                viewDictionary,
                new TempDataDictionary(actionContext.HttpContext, _tempDataProvider),
                sw,
                new HtmlHelperOptions()
            );

            await viewResult.View.RenderAsync(viewContext);
            return sw.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

**Things i have tried**

- Setting MvcRazorCompileOnPublish to false
- Installing the dotnet core SDK on the testing server

Comment: Haven't tried to do this myself, but if the views are being rendered server-side, then I believe you need the SDK there for that, not just the runtime, as is typical. An alternative might be to publish your app self-contained, but not sure if that's enough.

Comment: Is the latest asp.net core installed on the server?

Comment: @ChrisPratt I will try to install the SDK

Comment: @mxmissile yes, the latest version is installed

Comment: How did you publish? If you publish to the dev environment, will it work? Run `dotnet --info` in production env and share us the result.

Comment: @TaoZhou It did not solve the problem. I publish to prod env using the publishing tool in visual studio. Here is the result of the ```dotnet --info```




``` .NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.2.101 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.2.104 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNe
tCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNe
tCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.
App]

```

Comment: Do you mean this issue exist in the dev environement?

Comment: I really dont know @TaoZhou

Comment: Where did you develop and debug your project? Try to publish in this computer to check whether it is related with computer environemnt.

Comment: @TaoZhou Thanks for the tip, i tried and it fails on my computer also

Comment: @Shomlings The recommended way to let the world know that you found an answer to your own question is to create an actual *Answer* containing the found Solution, instead of putting the Solution inside the question. Would be great if you could do that (it might even get you some upvotes on the Answer).

Comment: Answers go in answers, and *accepted answers* tell us that the question has been solved. You can recover the "solution" content if you want to write an answer by looking in the edit history.

Answer (score 0):

I tried setting MvcRazorCompileOnPublish to false, and then it worked.. i tried this earlier but then it didn't work, maybe i typed it wrong or put it in the wrong place or  something :/

**Put his code into the {projectname}.csproj file:**

```
<MvcRazorExcludeRefAssembliesFromPublish>false</MvcRazorExcludeRefAssembliesFromPublish>
```

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>

    <!--ADD THIS LINE-->
    <MvcRazorExcludeRefAssembliesFromPublish>false</MvcRazorExcludeRefAssembliesFromPublish>

    <TypeScriptToolsVersion>3.1</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
```